# Saving a bytearray as a jpeg

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html5-canvas

I downloaded some code from codeproject that is called signaturecanvas, and it uses the HTML5 control canvas to generate a signature control. It works pretty good. But i'm stuck on this part. I can't figure out how to save the signaturebytearray as a jpeg image so i can display it after?

Link to javascript source:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/432675/Building-a-Signature-Control-Using-Canvas

## default.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <link href="signature.css" rel="scripts/stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/signature.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function loaded() {
            var signature = new ns.SignatureControl({
                containerId: 'container', callback: function () {
                    var signatureByteArray = signature.getSignatureImage();
                }
            });
            signature.init();
        }

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);

    </script>  
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="container">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily there is no need to send raw data to the server - just modify this function in the canvas control -

Change this in `signature.js`:

```
function getSignatureImage() {
    return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
}
```

to instead do this (or add a new function with a different name - but for example):

```
function getSignatureImage(quality) {
    return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', (quality ? quality : 0.7));
}
```

Now it will return a data-uri instead which you can set as image source to an element:

```
var img = new Image;
img.src = signature.getSignatureImage();
```

or if you want more or less compression provide a quality argument:

```
img.src = signature.getSignatureImage(0.5);
```

The data-uri contains a header and the image data (JPEG file) as base64 encoded string. You can extract the base64 data or store it as-is depending on your needs.

A little bit about the formats:

The byte-data returned from the original function is a byte-array containing all the data uncompressed including an alpha channel (bytes = width * height * 4). This is not trivial to compress on client side for technical reasons and sending it to server means you send a raw uncompressed image which gives a big overhead.

In the case of data-uri you get a JPEG (or PNG) compressed image encoded as base-64. The base-64 encoding adds 33% overhead compared to original data but is still a better alternative size-wise than sending raw data.

With this approach you don't really have to do much on the server side unless you want to store the binary data which in case you just chop of the header and base-64 decode the rest of data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to send the byte array to the server and save it there. So maybe add a "Save" button and post the signature using ajax:

```
$.post("saveimage.aspx", { sig: signature.getSignatureImage() }, function() { alert('Signature saved'); });
```

And then in saveimage.aspx, or wherever you want to save the signature image, something like:

```
byte[] bitmap = (byte[])Request.Form["sig"];
using(Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bitmap)))
{
    image.Save("signature.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```